# Android - Drawable path

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have small application written in android.

From SQLite database, I'm fetching some categories and icon names like (hotels, apartments, etc.). All examples of images I have in `drawable` folder.

Now I'm trying to read those images and show them in list but I have problem with drawable path. The error is always: `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.

Here is code example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, null, true);

    Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getContext().getPackageName()+"/drawable/");
    String drawable_path = otherPath.toString();

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), drawable_path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    TextView categoryID = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.category_id);

    txtTitle.setText(items.get(position));
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(drawable_path+imageIds.get(position)+"\""));
    categoryID.setText(category_ids.get(position));

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Gabe Sechan** gave me an great idea so I fixed this problem. If anyone have the same problem here is the answer.

Store names in DB and then convert it to `int` so you can set the image resource. Here is the code:

```
int resID = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(imageIds.get(position),
            "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());

imageView.setImageResource(resID);
```

Hope this will help someone. For my project is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I really do not suggest your access your drawables this way.  The ids used are not stable, any new release could break the linkage.  If you have to reference them via an external db, I'd either write the drawables out to the filesystem and reference them as normal files, or I'd store the drawable name in the db and get the id via lookup, then reference it via that id.

Comment: Can you give me some example how to do it through lookup?